# Angular "bind twice"

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to keep my watches down by using one-time binding (::) in most places.

However, I've run into the situation where I need to wait for one property of an object to arrive from our server.

Is there someway I can make Angular bind twice (first to a placeholder and second to the actual value)?

I tried accomplishing this using bindonce but it did not seem to work (I am guessing this is because bindonce wants to watch an entire object, not a single property).

Another solution would be if I could somehow remove a watch from the templates after the value comes in, if that is possible.

My objects look something like this:

```
{
 name: 'Name',
 id: 'Placeholder'
}
```

And my template:

```
<div ng-repeat="object in objects">
 {{::object.name}}
 {{::object.id}}
</div>
```

Id will change once and only once in the application life time, having a watch forever for a value that will only change once feels wasteful as we'll have many of these objects in the list.

Comment: Initialize the id with null or undefined, instead of initializing it with 'Placeholder'.

Comment: Yes, I tried this (and it works) but was told that it's not acceptable to not display anything while we wait for the value to arrive (the wait time may vary, between a few ms and a few s).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for! [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/69yRJy1Yfr53oqxK6UmT?p=preview)

I just wrote a bind-twice directive and if I did not completely missed the question it should solve your problem:

```
directive("bindTwice", function($interpolate) {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      scope: false,
      link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        var changeCount = 0;

        var cancelFn = scope.$watch(iAttrs.bindTwice, function(value) {
          iElement.text(value === undefined ? '' : value);
          changeCount++;
          if (changeCount === 3) {
            cancelFn();
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

What I do is, I add a watcher on the scope element we need to watch and update the content just like `ng-bind` does. But when `changeCount` hit the limit I simply cancel `$watch` effectively cleaning it from watchlist.

Usage:

```
  <body ng-controller="c1">
    <div ng-repeat="t in test">
      <p>{{ ::t.binding }}</p>
      <p bind-twice="t.binding"></p>
      <p>{{ t.binding }}</p>  
    </div>
  </body>
```

Please see [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/69yRJy1Yfr53oqxK6UmT?p=preview) for working example.